# Expiring session using session variable and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, session

Hey guys i wanna check session of a logged in user in php dynamically.

I presently use:

```
$now = time();
if($now < $_SESSION['expire'])
{
//continue session
}
else
{
//exit
}
```

I would like to implement the same using javascript and dynamically check the variable every 60 secs. Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Comment: You can use ajax to check the value of a php variable.

Comment: Take a look at this http://w3lessons.info/2014/01/01/how-to-check-expired-sessions-using-php-jquery-ajax/

Comment: You cannot check a session variable at clientside. But if you know how long session expiry is, you can reset a "session access" variable, and assume the session expired when sufficient time expires after last "session access". However, checking with AJAX is probably not the solution, since each time you send an AJAX request, you refresh the session.

Comment: i prefer not to go with ajax and with php/jquery/javascript. can u elaborate on how to do so?

Comment: Better solution than ajax and js.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Comment: i currently use maxlifetime and cookies now i would like to prompt my user the session is going to expire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkSession() {
setInterval(function(){
     var now = Date.now();
     $.get('ajax.php?timestamp='+now,function(data){
        return true;
     });
},60000);
}
checkSession();
</script>

<?php 
    //In your ajax.php
    $timestamp = $_REQUEST['timestamp'];
    if($timestamp < $_SESSION['expire']) {
        //continue session
    } else {
        session_destroy();
    }
?>
```